# PublishingPageImage Field is missing when get data through Rest Api to Pages Lib 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, rest

I want to get `PublishingPageImage`field value on REST API method on Pages library with below script.

```
 executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appwebUrl);
 executor.executeAsync({
    url: appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?@target='" + hostwebUrl + "';
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
    success: function (data) {
        // var results = data.d.results;
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
        var results = jsonObject.d.results;


    },
    error: function (data) {
    }
});
```

I got all the field of collection but seem to miss it out `PublishingPageImage` field in output.

i have try to get using select method but got error that `PublishingPageImage` Field is not exist on list.

like this :

```
 url: appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?@target='" + hostwebUrl + "'&$select=PublishingPageImage;
```

Anyone try this?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible to retrieve `Publishing Image` fields directly in SharePoint 2013 REST.

But there is a workaround, publishing fields could be retrieved using `ListItem.FieldValuesAsHtml` property via SharePoint REST endpoint as demonstrated below

> Limitation: it requires to perform two requests.

### How to retrieve Publishing fields using SharePoint 2013 REST

```
function getJson(endpointUri, success, error) 
{    
    $.ajax({       
       url: endpointUri,   
       type: "GET",   
       processData: false,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: {   
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }, 
       success: success,
       error: error
    });
}


function getPublishingPage(webUrl,listName,listItemId,publishingProperties, success, failure) 
{
    var itemUri =  webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")";  
    getJson(itemUri,
       function(data){
           var pageItem = data.d;

           var selectProperties = [];  
           for(var idx in publishingProperties){
               if(!pageItem.hasOwnProperty(publishingProperties[idx])){
                   selectProperties.push(publishingProperties[idx]);
               }
           }
           if(selectProperties.length > 0) {
              //construct an additional query 
              var query = '/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=' + selectProperties.join(',');
              var endpointUri = pageItem['__metadata'].uri + query;
              getJson(endpointUri,
                 function(data){
                    for(var property in data.d){
                       if(property == "__metadata") continue; 
                       pageItem[property] = data.d[property];   
                    }
                    success(pageItem);  
                 },
                 failure);
           } 
           else {
              success(pageItem);
           }   
        },
       failure);
}
```

**Usage**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve page fields including publishing fields, such as `PublishingPageImage`:

```
getPublishingPage(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Pages',3,['PublishingRollupImage','PublishingPageImage'],printPageDetails,logError);

function printPageDetails(pageItem)
{
    console.log('Page Publishing Image ' + pageItem.PublishingPageImage);
}

function logError(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Comment: This answer is excellent but by using this we are fetching data of only one item. 
can we make call and fetch publishing column data of Multiple Items???

Comment: @salah9, it is doable as well, I would suggest  to post another question for that matter